# How to display Google Analytics' active visitors on site' number on my website?

Tags: google-analytics

Google Analytics' new version has *Real Time (beta)*, and it is able to show the *number of active visitors on site*.

I am wondering how to display this number on my website.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Right now you can't do that through the Google Analytics API but there is a feature request in for it.

[Issue 154: Access to Real Time data](http://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=154)

Update: Google has added a real time api: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/

[Announcement](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2013/08/google-analytics-launches-real-time-api.html)

Update2: "The [Google Analytics superProxy](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-super-proxy) allows you to publicly share your Google Analytics reporting data."

Comment: real time api still in preview beta only.