# Google analytics pulling current number of users on site

Tags: python, google-analytics

I am atempting to pull the number of users on the site using googles analytics using the python. I can do the following an it works fine.

```
  return analytics.reports().batchGet(
      body={
        'reportRequests': [
        {
          'viewId': VIEW_ID,
          'dateRanges': [{'startDate': 'today', 'endDate': 'today'}],
          'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'}],
          'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:country'}],
        }]
      }
  ).execute()
```

and I get the number of sessions today.  However what I want is the number of current sessions.  The only thing I could find on this was on [googles documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=user&jump=ga_sessioncount)

where it says to use ga:sessionCount. which when I run that I get the following error:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet?alt=json returned "Unknown metric(s): ga:sessionCount
For details see https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets.">
```

So to be clear what I'm trying to pull is the current number of users on my website at the moment.  Thanks.

Edit: If there was something like timeNow for startDate I would be fine with that.

Comment: note: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245690/how-to-display-google-analytics-active-visitors-on-site-number-on-my-website is not about actually pulling the data and this is not what I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Dimensions & Metrics Explorer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=user&jump=ga_sessioncount) ga:sessionCount is a Dimension and NOT a metric.

Try:

```
'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:sessionCount'}]
```